# I get no results from ssh2_exec() with a mysql command

Tags: php, mysql, linux, ssh, libssh2

I got a problem. 
My PHP script abort if i run an mysql command:

```
ssh2_exec($session, 'mysql -sse "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table"');
```

With putty is the command no problem. Any other commands like 'll -la' or what else are no problem.

Can u tell me why it isn't working?

Bye mok

Comment: First you have to connect with mysql server after that you can run the sql commands.

Comment: And instead of using ssh2_exec(), use a database extension like PHP Data Objects (PDO). It will help make your queries more secure by using bindParam (Binds a parameter to the specified variable name). "The PHP Data Objects (PDO) extension defines a lightweight, consistent interface for accessing databases in PHP." - http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

Comment: Not sure, I was looking for a way to do back-office queries as root without allowing root for remote connections, and `ssh2` were a good solution.

Comment: PDO isnt possible for me, becuase the mysql server is ver. 4.1+.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay... i got it now.

The command "mysql" is in my system an alias to "mysql -u user -ppassword".
But if u do a connection wit ssh2_exec() all alias are unknown.

All i have to do is this.

```
ssh2_exec($session, 'mysql -u user -ppassword -sse "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table"');
```

Thank U!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the `-sse` option, but I guess your problem is that `ssh2_exec` returns a stream and not a string.

You can try using:

```
$stream = ssh2_exec($session, 'echo "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table" | mysql');
$output = stream_get_contents($stream);
```

Comment: first -sse is... -s = silent output (without borders), -ss = (without borders and headlines), -e = execute... all together -sse :) I know that ssh2_exec() returns a stream, i thougth it isn't necessary to post it :)